# How to fill a column conditionally

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset in which one of the columns needs to be filled conditionally. The conditions are that for equal lot numbers, the dates that are older (and equal) would be filled with 123ABC while dates that are newer (and equal) would be filled with 789XYZ. In the case of only one available date then it should be filled with 123ABC.

[image]

I tried the following code but it is filling the first 3 cells as 123ABC and rest of the cells as 789XYZ.

[image]

Please help.

```
    Dim F As Worksheet
    Set F = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    Dim j As Long
    Do While F.Range("C2").Offset(i, 0) <> ""
        If F.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0) = "" Then
            j = 0
            Do While F.Range("C2").Offset(j, 0) <> ""
                If (Abs(DateDiff("d", F.Range("C2").Offset(i, 0).Value, F.Range("C2").Offset(j, 0).Value)) <= 5) And (F.Range("B2").Offset(i, 0) = F.Range("B2").Offset(j, 0)) Then
                    F.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value = "123ABC"
                    Else
                    F.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value = "789XYZ"
                    GoTo Next_Blank
                End If
            j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If
Next_Blank:
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next approach. It should be very fast even for large ranges. It uses a dictionary to create "Lot" unique keys, keeping the value as the most recent Date. Then it uses arrays and works only in memory, dropping the processed array content at one, at the end of the code:

```
Sub FillColumn()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, arrFin, dict As Object
   Const beforeD As String = "123ABC", maxD As String = "789XYZ"
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in "B:B"
   
   arr = sh.Range("A1:C" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   
   'fill a dictionary with unique lots and most recent Date:
   Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
   For i = 2 To UBound(arr)  'iterate between the array row
        'create dictionary unique keys with most recent Date as item:
        dict(arr(i, 2)) = IIf(CDate(arr(i, 3)) > CDate(dict(arr(i, 2))), CDate(arr(i, 3)), CDate(arr(i, 3)))
   Next i
   arrFin = arr 'initialize arrFin as the initial one

   For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the arr items
        If CDate(arr(i, 3)) < dict(arr(i, 2)) Then 'for a Date before existing one in column B:B:
            arrFin(i, 1) = beforeD                 'place the string beforeD
        Else
            arrFin(i, 1) = maxD                    'place the string maxD
        End If
   Next i
   'drop the array content at once:
   sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version, which place "123ABC" if a single `Date` is found for the same "Lot", as required in your comment:

```
Sub FillColumn2()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, arrFin, dict As Object
   Const beforeD As String = "123ABC", maxD As String = "789XYZ"
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A1:C" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   
   'fill a dictionary with unique lots and most recent Date:
   Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
   Dim arrExist
   For i = 2 To UBound(arr)  'iterate between the array row
        'create dictionary unique keys with most recent Date as item, and False for only one Date found:
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 2), Array(CDate(arr(i, 3)), False)  'False means only one Date
        Else
            If CDate(arr(i, 3)) > dict(arr(i, 2))(0) Then
                arrExist = dict(arr(i, 2))                      'place existing dictionary item in an array (to be changed)
                arrExist(0) = CDate(arr(i, 3)): arrExist(1) = True 'True means that a second graiter Date has been found
                dict(arr(i, 2)) = arrExist
            End If
        End If
   Next i
   arrFin = arr 'initialize arrFin as the initial one

   For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the arr items
        If CDate(arr(i, 3)) < dict(arr(i, 2))(0) Or dict(arr(i, 2))(1) = False Then  'check also the second item array element (boolean)
            arrFin(i, 1) = beforeD                    'place the string beforeD, also for the case of the same date
        Else
            arrFin(i, 1) = maxD                       'place the string maxD
        End If
   Next i
   'drop the array content at once:
   sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

A dictionary can keep any data type, but it has a peculiarity: if the dictionary item is an array **it cannot be modified directly in the item**. That's why the code uses `arrExist` to take the dictionary item, modify it and place it back.

It is also good to know that Excel keeps a `Date` as a `Long` number. That's why comparing the existing dictionary item (when empty) with a lower number would never change the item. No date less then zero can be supplied...

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It works good.

I have a quick question please. For cases where there is only one date can I modify the code to print only "123ABC" please?

Right now for cases where there is only one date and equal lots the code is printing "789XYZ". Thanks again!

Comment: In your code how is it able to keep only the most recent dates please? I tried changing the 'greater than' sign to 'less than sign' but it still kept only the most recent dates. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: @Anchal Sondhi 1. You did not specify this condition in your question. 2. Of course, it is possible, but the code logic must be changed. The cases of **the same date** should be processed during the dictionary loading and set a second variable to be adapted in such a case and used when fill the constants. I can post a version able to also cover such a situation.

Comment: @Anchal Sondhi  Since the initial dictionary item value is `0`, you cannot supply a `Date` less than this one... I can show you how to do that, but if you tried it in order to solve the first issue you raised, it will be useless, I am afraid. So, I will adapt the above code to also handle the case **of the same date**, as required in the comment. It will also be good **to edit your question and state this requirement there**. And I also like to inform that we here, when somebody answer our question, as it has been formulated, we tick the code left side check box, to make it **accepted answer**

Comment: @Anchal Sondhi OK. Added a new version able do deal as you required for the cases of the same unique Date per Lot. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It worked like magic. I need to learn more on VBA using dictionary and arrays. Could you point me in the right direction please?

And I am very grateful for this help .Appreciate for all this.

Comment: And my bad about not able to tell about my data's structure before. I would be more careful in future. Thanks again.

Comment: I mostly learned by trying... No any course. There are a lot of places on internet where you can find interesting examples. For dictionary [here](https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-dictionary/) and for arrays [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)...

Comment: Thanks so much for the links. These are very helpful. And appreciate all the help with this.